# terminator 0.98 with xpra 0.15.10 on 14.04

Tags: dbus, terminator, remote-x-session

i need to be running on 14.04 for now, no upgrade possibilities. And I need to run from remote X (tghus using xpra). Now, I realized that 1 terminatot 0.97`has some issues especially when it's about storing a layout with multiple tabs. Now,`terminator 0.98`has received a few nbug fixes in these regsards, so I wanted to try it out but now all of a sudden, terminaor requitres`DBUS`which I don't have with`xpra`, there's an option to start terminator with "Disable DBUS"`-u` but even when I do that, I get this:

```
ron@jpax-build07:~/tmp/terminator-0.98$ ./terminator -u
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":111".
/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/terminator.py:92: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/terminator.py:92: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/terminator.py:92: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/terminator.py:92: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)

(terminator:30729): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-5OyZC2BY3k: Connection refused

(terminator:30729): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-nTkOFlKch9: Connection refused

(terminator:30729): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-oG45uRzj3v: Connection refused

(terminator:30729): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-rGr2HCoTB1: Connection refused

(terminator:30729): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ueZEKLa4oK: Connection refused

** (terminator:30729): WARNING **: Binding '<Shift><Control><Alt>a' failed!
Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.
PluginRegistry::load_plugins: Importing plugin __init__.py failed: 'module' object has no attribute 'AVAILABLE'

(terminator:30729): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-7qFt8NaeIk: Connection refused

(terminator:30729): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-O26NS8auRj: Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./terminator", line 118, in <module>
    TERMINATOR.create_layout(OPTIONS.layout)
  File "/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/terminator.py", line 265, in create_layout
    window, terminal = self.new_window()
  File "/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/terminator.py", line 192, in new_window
    terminal = maker.make('Terminal')
  File "/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/factory.py", line 94, in make
    output = func(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/factory.py", line 106, in make_terminal
    return(terminal.Terminal())
  File "/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/terminal.py", line 178, in __init__
    self.reconfigure()
  File "/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/terminal.py", line 782, in reconfigure
    self.titlebar.update()
  File "/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/titlebar.py", line 113, in update
    title_font = pango.FontDescription(self.config.get_system_prop_font())
  File "/home/ron/tmp/terminator-0.98/terminatorlib/config.py", line 371, in get_system_prop_font
    '/desktop/gnome/interface/font_name')
glib.GError: No D-BUS daemon running

ron@jpax-build07:~/tmp/terminator-0.98$
```

so, how can I either get DBUS started with Xpra or terminator running without DBUS?
(terminator 0.97 works just fine without DBUS).

Answer (score 0):

Why not start dbus?

```
dbus-launch xpra start ...
```

Newer versions of xpra do this for you automatically.